# Will flashing a custom fix lag on my Android?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rom-flashing, rom, performance, ram

I have a 1 GB RAM tablet running a pretty much vanilla Android Jelly Bean 4.1.1 and it's been running very slow. Apps startup time have been slow, noticeable lag exists while scrolling between the home screens, and apps crash sometimes. Browsing on the Internet has scroll lag and I have many more problems. I know that 1GB of RAM is more than enough to run Jelly Bean smoothly without any lag. How will rooting my device or flashing any custom ROMs help? I am new to the Android world, any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Can't tell from your post what manufacturer made your tablet. If it's Samsung, their TouchWiz application tends to muck up occasionally, like lagging. This is more evident in Android 4.2 than 4.1. Worst case, backup your app and data, do a factory reset, reinstall your favourite apps and see if the lagging return. Custom ROMs might eliminate the lagging, but no guarantee.

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure about the hardware of your tablet ,so might not be that powerful .That could be the reason for the lag 
About rooting and custom roms they are not assured to remove lag  ,some roms might help while some may be even slower, it **depends on the rom** You use .But that said generally custom roms are made to be **lightweight ,fast and fluid**.